# Is this a bug in System.Net.HttpClient on Rio?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

This is the function found in Delphi Rio in `System.Net.HttpClient`

```
THTTPClientHelper = class helper for THTTPClient
....

procedure THTTPClientHelper.SetExt(const Value);
var
{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
  LRelease: Boolean;
{$ENDIF}
  LExt: THTTPClientExt;
begin
  if FHTTPClientList = nil then
    Exit;
  TMonitor.Enter(FHTTPClientList);
  try
{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
    LRelease := not FHTTPClientList.ContainsKey(Self);
{$ENDIF}
    LExt := THTTPClientExt(Value);
    FHTTPClientList.AddOrSetValue(Self, LExt);
{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
    if LRelease then __ObjRelease;
{$ENDIF}
  finally
    TMonitor.Exit(FHTTPClientList);
  end;
end;
```

What the guy try to do with `LRelease` here?

```
{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
    LRelease := not FHTTPClientList.ContainsKey(Self);
{$ENDIF}
    LExt := THTTPClientExt(Value);
    FHTTPClientList.AddOrSetValue(Self, LExt);
{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
    if LRelease then __ObjRelease;
{$ENDIF}
```

So if `FHTTPClientList` doesn't contain the `THTTPClient` add it in the `FHTTPClientList` and then **reduce it's refcount by one**. Why reduce it's refcount by one?? the `THTTPClient` is still alive and used why breaking it's refcount? Their is a bug here, maybe the guy make a typo, but i don't understand what he want to do originally ...

for info this this how items are removing from the dictionary :

```
procedure THTTPClientHelper.RemoveExt;
begin
  if FHTTPClientList = nil then
    Exit;
  TMonitor.Enter(FHTTPClientList);
  try
    FHTTPClientList.Remove(Self);
  finally
    TMonitor.Exit(FHTTPClientList);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I would have to look deeper... but it looks like simulating dictionary that contains weak references.

Comment: @Dalija: indeed. It looks as if the HttpClientList does not own the keys it contains, so indeed, that is some kind of weak refererence.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes it's look, but when removing the item from the dictionary () it's also decrease the refcount and that is definitively not like dictionary of weak reference... and if they want a dictionary of weak reference why not use pointer instead ?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis : look what i answer to Dalija and also the final note in question I just edited ... Also I don't understand why the guy would want a dictionary of weak reference

Comment: I'm smiling at the code that does two dictionary lookups where one would suffice if the dictionary class was better designed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ! agreed and I asked embt to addi the method TryAdd in the dictionary and they did it in Rio :) https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13502

Comment: When you manually fiddle with reference counting, you have to do it properly. So, yes, decreasing reference count in one method should be accompanied with increasing in another. That looks like a bug to me. Why not use pointers - with pointers you lose type safety.

Comment: TryAdd does nothing here. If it fails you need to set the value still. You'd use AddOrSetValue and check whether or not Count changed. Sorry to be off topic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but here he don' need to do 2 roundtrips he just need to do one addOrSetValue :) no need to call ContainsKey :)

Comment: Well, assuming the code is correct it behaves differently depending on whether or not the key is already in the dict. Which you can test using count.

Comment: This seems to be just a dirty trick to add some fields to THTTPClient (I still cannot see any reason why these cannot be added to the class directly). The dictionary FHTTPClientList has to hold weak references, because otherwise a THTTPClient would never be freed unter ARC. While it is only called in THTTPClient.Destroy the missing refcount correction in RemoveExt is not relevant any more.
To be honest: I don't like this programming style.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar no reference counting mater in fact! for exemple if you create a tlist<ThttpClient> ... then when you will do MyList.clear the Tlist will first call httpClient.disposeOF on each of it's items and then after this list will clean it's array by calling httpClient.freeInstance on each of it's item and here you will have access violation because the previous disposeOF already decrease the refcount to 0 (instead of 1 because object is still owned by the TList) and thus already free the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purpose of the manual reference counting for ARC compiler in above code is simulating dictionary with weak references. Delphi generic collections are backed with generic arrays that will hold strong reference to any object added to the collection on ARC compiler.

There is several ways to achieve weak references - using pointers, using wrappers around object where object is declared as weak and manual reference counting in appropriate places.

With pointers you lose type safety, wrappers require significantly more code, so I guess the author of above code opted for manual reference counting. Nothing wrong with that part.

However, as you noticed, there is something fishy in that code - while `SetExt` routine is written properly `RemoveExt` has a bug resulting in a crash later on.

Let's go through the code in context on ARC compiler (I will omit compiler directives and unrelated code for brevity):

Since adding object into collection (array) increases reference count, to achieve weak reference we have to decrease reference count of the added object instance - that way the instance's reference count will remain the same after it is stored in collection. Next, when we remove object from such collection, we have to restore reference count balance and increase reference count. Also we have to make sure that object will be removed from such collection before it is destroyed - good place to do that is destructor.

**Adding to collection:**

```
LRelease := not FHTTPClientList.ContainsKey(Self);
FHTTPClientList.AddOrSetValue(Self, LExt);
if LRelease then __ObjRelease;
```

We add the object to the collection and then after collection holds strong reference to our object we can release it's reference count. If object is already inside collection that means it's reference count was already decreased and we must not decrease it again - that is the purpose of `LRelease` flag.

**Removing from collection:**

```
if FHTTPClientList.ContainsKey(Self) then
  begin
    __ObjAddRef;
    FHTTPClientList.Remove(Self);
  end;
```

If object is in collection we have to restore the balance and increase the reference count before removing object from collection. This is the part that is missing from `RemoveExt` method.

**Making sure that object is not in the list upon destruction:**

```
destructor THTTPClient.Destroy;
begin
  RemoveExt;
  inherited;
end;
```

**Note:** In order for such *faked* weak collection to work properly items must be added and removed only through above methods that take care of balancing reference count. Using any other original collection methods like `Clear` will result in broken reference count.

---

**Bug or not?**

In `System.Net.HttpClient` code *broken* `RemoveExt` method is called only in destructor, also `FHTTPClientList` is private variable and it is not altered in any other way. On the first glimpse, that code works properly, but actually contains rather subtle bug.

To unravel the real bug we need to cover possible usage scenarios, starting with few established facts:

1. Only methods that alter content and by that reference count of items in `FHTTPClientList` dictionary are `SetExt` and `RemoveExt` methods
2. `SetExt` method is correct
3. Broken `RemoveExt` method that does not call `__ObjAddRef` is called only in `THTTPClient` destructor and this is where this *subtle* bug originates.

When destructor is called upon any particular object instance that means object instance has reached it's lifetime, and any subsequent reference counting triggers (during destructor execution) have no influence on the code correctness.

That is ensured by applying `objDestroyingFlag` on `FRefCount` variable changing its value and any further count increasing/decreasing can no longer result in special value `0` that starts destruction process - so object is safe and will not get destroyed twice.

In above code when `THTTPClient` destructor is called that means last strong reference to object instance has gone out of scope or was set to `nil` and at that moment the only remaining live reference that can trigger reference counting mechanism is the one in `FHTTPClientList`. That reference has been cleared by `RemoveExt` method (broken or not) at that point as previously said it does not matter. And everything works fine.

But, author of the code has forgotten one tiny weeny thingy - `DisposeOf` method that triggers the destructor, but at that point object instance has not reached its reference counting lifetime. In other words - if destructor is called by `DisposeOf`, any subsequent reference counting triggers **must be balanced** because there are still live references to the object that will trigger reference counting mechanism after the destructor chain calls are completed. If we break the counting at that point result will be catastrophic.

Since `THTTPClient` is not `TComponent` descendant that **requires** `DisposeOf` it is easy to make the oversight and forget that someone, somewhere could call `DipsoseOf` on such variable anyway - for instance if you make owned list of `THTTPClient` instances clearing such list will call `DisposeOf` on them and happily break their reference count because `RemoveExt` method is ultimately broken.

**Conclusion: Yes, it is a BUG.**

Comment: Perhaps I miss something, but doesn't the explizit __ObjAddRef and implizit __ObjRelease trigger FreeInstance call inside THTTPClient.Destroy? When entering Destroy the objDisposedFlag should be set in FRefCount. While __ObjAddRef will increase it, __ObjRelease, when decreasing it and masking the ObjDisposedFlag, will have Result = 0. The following __SetDisposed will return False as objDisposedFlag is already set. Therefore FreeInstance is called.
This won't happen if the __ObjAddRef call is missing, because decrementing the refcount will not return 0.

Comment: @UweRaabe when (before) object hits destructor for the first time, its reference count is flagged with objDestroyingFlag and further calls to __ObjRelease and __ObjAddRef will have no influence.

Comment: I cannot see that in the code. Neither __ObjAddRef nor __ObjRelease check for objDestroyingFlag. Only BeforeDestruction does.

Comment: @UweRaabe they don't need to check. Value of FRefCount variable will be set to -2147483648 and incrementing/decrementing that value will hardly reach zero again.

Comment: OK, I can see it now.

Comment: Piggy-backing ARC on libraries with strong reference handling is too complex and bug-ridden. Fortunately the ARC model as implemented is soon gone.

Comment: @LURD Actually, this is not the case here. It is just that sometimes you need weak collections, and this is how you handle them under ARC compiler - any ARC compiler for that matter.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Why this particular HTTP Client code actually works properly? >> as i previously say, it's not work if you call disposeOF and still keep a reference to the disposed object like TList does

Comment: Because of how it is used in current code. But if you modify that code then it can break, for various reasons.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar... no need to modify that code, simply call MyHttpClient.dispose and it's enaught to make an exception if you still think that you own an (disposed) instance of the object

Comment: Er... yes, DisposeOf needs proper reference counting... in that case code is broken after all... I will double check tomorrow.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar ... no problem I stuck on this problem because my app was doing access violation because of this so I know :) but if someone can explain me why embt decide to create this ugly helper THTTPClientHelper instead of directly puting everything inside THTTPClient I will be very thankfull !